# Strong Induction - Any integer greater than 1 is divisible by a prime number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove any integer greater than 1 is divisible by a prime number(strong induction)

Let P(n) be an integer divisible by a prime number, where n>=2.

Base Case:

Show true for $P(2)$

$P(2)$ is true because 2 is a prime number itself.

Inductive Case:

Show that for integers $k>2$, if true for all $i$ with $2<=i<k$, then it's true for k.

Suppose that for all integers i with $2<=i<k$, i is divisible by a prime number (inductive hypothesis)

If someone could explain how the inductive case above works that would be appreciated

Comment: Fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Comment: Hint: if $k \gt 1$ is not divisible by *any* integer $\gt 1$ except itself, then $k$ is a prime number (at least that's what I assume is the definition you use). Otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Either $k$ is prime, in which case we're done, or else $k = ab$ for some $1 < a, b < k$. By the induction hypothesis there is some prime number, $p$ that divides $a$. $p$ divides $k$ too.